# Installing Rubber Parts Final Tightening Carried Under Unladen Condition With Tires On Ground

Tags: suspension, torque

If the weather permits I will be replacing some front end suspension parts on my Nissan Almeras N16 2006. The transverse link/control arm, tie rod ends, stabilizer bar bushings and stabilizer connecting rods. The manual that I have states: '***When installing rubber parts, final tightening must be carried out under unladen condition* with tires on the ground. *Fuel, radiator coolant and engine oil full.***'

[image]

It isn't clear to me at least, what parts would this specifically refer to? For some parts there is limited/impossible access so guess that would rule them out?

What is actually meant by '**rubber parts**'? Tie rod ends? Stabilizer rods? Lower ball joints? As all of these have a rubber cup.

Furthermore does '**Final tightening**' mean torqued to spec? So tighten it so that part is snug but then torque it to spec? As if the incorrect rubber parts aren't torqued and have load on them when they shouldn't I can imagine torqueing them at that stage wouldn't be of much use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing in your diagram I'm see where there are rubber parts are the lower A-frames. The bolts in question are circled in red. There will be a second set on the backside (which you can't see in the diagram), so four bolts in total. I'm not seeing any other points where rubber may be used except for the top of the struts, but those are not an issue.

The reason you want to torque these on the ground is because if you don't and tighten these in the air, when you do put them on the ground, there will be a torsion twist to the rubber which will cause it to prematurely wear. When on the ground and tightened, this is the position which there will normally (at rest) not be any twisting on the rubber, so this will minimize the wear. It will twist because ones the bolts are tight, it tightens against the inner sleeve which keeps you from crushing the parts which hold the bolts (the holes in the K-member which the steering rack is attached to). Hopefully this makes sense.

[image]

Comment: @Paulster2 Makes sense, just looked at the spare part and it would only be 1 bolt going through that section (circled in red for this A-frame), it's a hollow metal case (no threads) surrounded by rubber dampening if that makes sense similar to engine mount setup but guess the theory of the tightening would apply, other attachment on it is 3 bolts on other side.Would it be sufficient in that case if the final torque was 100Nm, 70Nm in the air and the final 100Nm on ground?

Comment: @Dave1UK - No. Just tighten it snug in the air, then torque it to spec on the ground. You don't want any torque on the bolt. If you do, it defeats the purpose.